How to emulate Telegram Mini-App InitData
How to emulate Telegram mini-app InitData object?
Can we somehow generate initData with those hash, for our personal account?
Just for fun and test purposes, ofcourse.
I think, that Telegram client generates hash of initData somehow based on Telegram user-id and time.
